# How can I make my ModelState be valid with empty fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, modelstate

I have 3 rows for achievement input on my page.
I want to ViewModel state to be valid even if only 1 of the rows are filled.
Right now the modelstate is only valid when I fill all 3 rows.

Do I have to make multiple constructors for this?

```
    public int AchievementsRank1 { get; set; }
    public string AchievementsEvent1 { get; set; }

    public int AchievementsRank2 { get; set; }
    public string AchievementsEvent2 { get; set; }

    public int AchievementsRank3 { get; set; }
    public string AchievementsEvent3 { get; set; }

    public EditProfileViewModel()
    {

    }

    public EditProfileViewModel(string username, int achievementsR1, string achievementsE1, int achievementsR2, string achievementsE2, int achievementsR3, string achievementsE3, string freetext, string social)
    {
        this.Username = username;
        this.AchievementsRank1 = achievementsR1;
        this.AchievementsEvent1 = achievementsE1;
        this.AchievementsRank2 = achievementsR2;
        this.AchievementsEvent2 = achievementsE2;
        this.AchievementsRank3 = achievementsR3;
        this.AchievementsEvent3 = achievementsE3;
        this.Freetext = freetext;
        this.SocialURL = social;
    }
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Index([Bind("Username,AchievementsRank1,AchievementsEvent1,AchievementsRank2,AchievementsEvent2,AchievementsRank3,AchievementsEvent3,Freetext,SocialURL")] EditProfileViewModel edit)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ProfileDTO dto = CreateDtoFromInput(edit);
            //commands.SaveNewProfile(dto);
            Profile prof = new Profile(dto);
            return View("Profile", prof);
        }
        else
        {
            return View(edit);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i recommend using key-value pair instead of having the fields separately

Comment: Implement `IValidatableObject` in the model class, return a list of custom errors based on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel validation are normally focused on 1 property.

You could create a custom annotation and kinda "combine" multiple properties and create your own validation rules. As you can read, this approach is using annotation instead of `bind(`.

I will also recommend to change from a lot of properties to one object as ViewModel, It will look cleaner.

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [CustomAnnotation(x,y,z)]
    [StringLength(1000)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Range(0, 999.99)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }

    public bool Preorder { get; set; }
}
```

Look a examples here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.0